# Is there a way to start appium server on mac machine remotely through windows and triggering ios tests on real device using python?

Tags: python, ios, macos, appium

I am currently trying to automate an iOS application on a real iOS device. For this I have setup all the necessary tools on MacBook like appium, xcode etc. The iOS application tests are written in Robot Framework, python. I want  to write a python script which can create ssh connection to MacBook remotely through Windows PC, start the appium server and then execute the iOS test on real iPhone. I want to know if there is a possibility to do this thing.

Thanks in advance.